# Conflict css header/footer

Tags: html, css

My footer background just disappear at 768px and it broke all the styling due to this media query in my header code:

```
[type="checkbox"], label {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav ul {
      display: none;
  }
```

How can I fix this problem?
I tried with multiple browsers, the footer is only working at less than 768px.

```
/* ----------------------------- Footer ------------------------------ */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300);

footer { background-color:#0c1a1e; min-height:350px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
.footerleft { margin-top:50px; padding:0 36px; }
.logofooter { margin-bottom:10px; font-size:25px; color:#fff; font-weight:700;}

.footerleft p { color:#fff; font-size:12px !important; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; margin-bottom:15px;}
.footerleft p i { width:20px; color:#999;}


.paddingtop-bottom {  margin-top:50px;}
.footer-ul { list-style-type:none;  padding-left:0px; margin-left:2px;}
.footer-ul li { line-height:29px; font-size:12px;}
.footer-ul li a { color:#a0a3a4; transition: color 0.2s linear 0s, background 0.2s linear 0s; }
.footer-ul i { margin-right:10px;}
.footer-ul li a:hover {transition: color 0.2s linear 0s, background 0.2s linear 0s; color:#ff670f; }

.social:hover {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
 }

 .icon-ul { list-style-type:none !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
 .icon-ul li { line-height:75px; width:100%; float:left;}
 .icon { float:left; margin-right:5px;}


 .copyright { min-height:40px; background-color:#000000;}
 .copyright p { text-align:left; color:#FFF; padding:10px 0; margin-bottom:0px;}
 .heading7 { font-size:21px; font-weight:700; color:#d9d6d6; margin-bottom:22px;}
 .post p { font-size:12px; color:#FFF; line-height:20px;}
 .post p span { display:block; color:#8f8f8f;}
 .bottom_ul { list-style-type:none; float:right; margin-bottom:0px;}
 .bottom_ul li { float:left; line-height:40px;}
 .bottom_ul li:after { content:"/"; color:#FFF; margin-right:8px; margin-left:8px;}
 .bottom_ul li a { color:#FFF;  font-size:12px;}
```

I'm using flask for the backend, so here's my html with jinja templates blocks:

```
  <header>
  <div class="inner">
    <nav>
      <a href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}" class="logo">My App Logo.</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav" /><label for="nav"></label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}">Home</a></li>       
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('user_page') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('trends') }}">Trends</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('pricing') }}">Pricing</a></li>
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('user_profile_page') }}">
        {{ current_user.first_name or current_user.user_auth.username }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('user.logout') }}">Sign out</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('user.login') }}">Sign in</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>          

<body>
{% block body %}


<footer>
{% block footer %}
    <div class="pull-left"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>  |  <a href="#">Terms Of Service</a></div>
    <div class="pull-right">&copy; 2017 All rights reserved.</div>

      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 footerleft ">
        <div class="logofooter"> Logo</div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley.</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i> 254, Fake Adress, California</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone (India) : +54 6846 887</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> E-mail : ihello@jkjd.com</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
        <h6 class="heading7">GENERAL LINKS</h6>
        <ul class="footer-ul">
          <li><a href="#"> Career</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Terms & Conditions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Client Gateway</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Ranking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Case Studies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Frequently Ask Questions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
        <h6 class="heading7">LATEST POST</h6>
        <div class="post">
          <p>facebook crack the movie advertisment code:what it means for you <span>August 3,2015</span></p>
          <p>facebook crack the movie advertisment code:what it means for you <span>August 3,2015</span></p>
          <p>facebook crack the movie advertisment code:what it means for you <span>August 3,2015</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" style="margin-bottom:15px;" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
          <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
</footer>

<div class="copyright">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>© 2016 - All Rights with Webenlance</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul class="bottom_ul">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Faq's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a schematic of your HTML. ***Dont*** post all of it, just the structural aspects we need to know what you're problem is.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the markup, but you probably need to more specifically the target your header `nav` because you probably have another `nav` element in your footer that is disappearing from the media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS in the media Query which you posted has nothing to do with the footer... But I have one idea: You posted this...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav ul {
  display: none;
}
```

...and wrote that this is in the your header code - whatever that means (inside a `style` tag?)

However, in that code I just posted, the closing curly bracket for the media query is missing. So close this - it could be the reason for your problem:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #inner > nav > ul {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked but the display: none is not working for header nav links. It stays visible and fixed at the top no matter the resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the @media query line sets the max-width to 768px, which means the footer won't go over the max-width. Try to change this value and see what happens.

Comment: Same problem at different resolution.